# Marginalizing conditional probabilities conditioned on multiple variables

Tags: conditional-probability, marginal-distribution

I am wondering if the following equality of marginalized conditional probabilities holds

$\sum_{x} p(x \vert y) = \sum_{x} p(x \vert y, z) = \sum_{x} p(x \vert y, z, w) = \sum_{x} p(x \vert y, z, w, v) = \cdots = 1$

If it does, I could swap out each of the terms for one-another and condition on arbitrary latent variables which I have a hard time wrapping my head around. (Is this something one would do in practice? Is it useful at all?)

Answer (score 1):

Each term in the equality you wrote is a sum over a probability distribution, which must sum to one by definition. So yes, the equality is true (it's like saying $1=1$). But, keep in mind that it's an equality between sums over the distributions, not between the distributions themselves. It does *not* imply that $p(x \mid y) = p(x \mid y, z)$, etc.